# My JavaScript variable (array) is modified during .trigger/.on process

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have a small function I use to process ajax request and get data from it.

Once all my JSON is aggregated in a array I fire an event.

My problem is that my variable `mySources`, an array, is modified during process. Before event triggering it is, as expected, an array of 4 arrays but after being "listened" it is only an array (not even one array in an array but only the first array).

```
 function setSources(){
        var deffereds = [];          
        if (arguments.length == 0)
            {
                deffereds.push(getTweets()),
                deffereds.push(getFacebookstatuses()),
                deffereds.push(getCampaigns()),
                deffereds.push(getArticles())
            }
            else
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                    if (arguments[i] == 'tweet'){
                        deffereds.push(getTweets())
                    }
                    else if (arguments[i] == 'facebookstatus'){
                        deffereds.push(getFacebookstatuses())
                    }
                    else if (arguments[i] == 'campaign'){
                        deffereds.push(getCampaigns())
                    }
                    else if (arguments[i] == 'article'){
                        deffereds.push(getArticles())
                    }                                               
                }
            }
                                    
            $.when.apply(null,deffereds).done(function(){                   
                var mySources = new Array();
                for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                  mySources[i]=$.parseJSON(arguments[i][2].responseText).objects; 
                };
                console.log(mySources); **// This gives me an array of 4 arrays as expected**
                $(document).trigger('cal/results',mySources); 
            });
        
        $(document).on('cal/mySources', function(e,mySources){
            console.dir(mySources); **// This gives me only the first of the 4 arrays**
     });
        
 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When passing an array as `extraParameters` to [`$.trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), the array is "unboxed" and each element is passed as a separate argument to the event handlers. Thus, your event handler is actually receiving:

```
function(e, mySources0, mySources1, mySources2, ...) { }
```

A simple solution is to just wrap your arguments in another array when calling `trigger`:

```
$(document).trigger('cal/results', [mySources]); // Note the extra brackets
```

So that should be an array of an array of four arrays... JavaScript is fun!

Comment: @MattBall The docs say: *An array of arguments can also be passed to the .trigger() call, and these parameters will be passed along to the handler as well following the event object.* I agree, it's not very clear if the array is passed *as-is*, but the wording *array of arguments* seems to suggest that it's unwrapped first. Either way, the code sample preceding that paragraph clearly demonstrates the unwrapping.

Comment: You sir are perfectly right, that did it. I swear I read the $.trigger docs 23 times today.

Comment: @Matthieu Yes, the docs don't always completely cover all uses and variants. Most of the time you can get away with inspecting the outcome (e.g. `console.log(arguments)`) but in some extreme cases, you just have to dive into the source code to figure out what's going on. In this case, the note *"only the first of the 4 arrays"* gave away that there may be some unwrapping going on.